# How to change the Terminal cursor from box to line?

Tags: linux, terminal

The box-like cursor in Linux Mints terminal (and ubuntus) is really confusing me! I am used to a vertical line so it's hard for me to focus on the commands when I am unsure where this box-ish cursor really is all the time.

Is there a way to change this?
Thanks!

Comment: I looked around prior to posting here but couldn't find anything of use...

Comment: Allright! I understand. Is there a way I can move this to a better place? Or should I just remove it? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a function of the Terminal program itself.

In Ubuntu, if you're using `terminal` you can change this in the terminal application preferences, which is accessible from the terminal application menu in the Ubuntu status bar in the top left of the screen.

```
Terminal Menu
  -> Preferences
    -> Profile
      -> Cursor
        -> Cursor Shape
          -> I-beam
```

There's a pull-down menu for "Cursor Shape" and "I beam" is an option.

Comment: This is an off-topic question. You should be voting to migrate it instead of answering it. :)

Comment: Brian, do you know if you CAN progamatically change this?  For example, if I `set -o vi` and press escape, i am not using VI-style keystrokes.  I'd like to change this to a box.  Can you do this somehow?

Comment: "I am **now** using vi-style keystrokes"

Comment: Actually, this settings has moved to a Profile's settings and there to the "Text" tab now.

Answer (score 21):

At the time the question was asked (October 2011), the way to do this with the given terminal was via its preferences dialog.  After a few years ([November 2014](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vte/commit/?id=430965a0bc372296555f859bcf56a358ea191507)), someone added support for the `DECSUSR` escape sequence which was used (and extended) in xterm since [December 2009](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_252).

The change mentions these choices:

```
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_TERMINAL_DEFAULT = 0,
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_BLINK_BLOCK      = 1,
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_STEADY_BLOCK     = 2,
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_BLINK_UNDERLINE  = 3,
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_STEADY_UNDERLINE = 4,
+        /* *_IBEAM are xterm extensions */
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_BLINK_IBEAM      = 5,
+        VTE_CURSOR_STYLE_STEADY_IBEAM     = 6
+} VteCursorStyle;
```

The feature is documented in [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-SP-q.1D81):

```
CSI Ps SP q
          Set cursor style (DECSCUSR, VT520).
            Ps = 0  -> blinking block.
            Ps = 1  -> blinking block (default).
            Ps = 2  -> steady block.
            Ps = 3  -> blinking underline.
            Ps = 4  -> steady underline.
            Ps = 5  -> blinking bar (xterm).
            Ps = 6  -> steady bar (xterm).
```

so that you could (for example) do this on the command-line to change the cursor to a bar ("I-beam"):

```
printf '\033[6 q'
```

(the space is needed, corresponds to "SP" in the documentation).

Comment: Thanks for this reference. This is really great and the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Can I make this state permanent? It resets to it's default every time I reboot the system (I'm using WSL).

Comment: For xterm, that would be resource-settings, for most terminals, in the shell login initialization, but for (gnome) terminal, there's neither documentation nor preference settings that apply consistently.

Answer (score 1):

In Bodhi 2.4.0  you can disable the blinking cursor ( less hindrance) 
: right-click empty space in terminal-window -> Settings ->Behaviour -> uncheck Blinking Cursor

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu Terminal window,right click on Terminal empty space.profiles>profile preferences>cursor shape>I-Beam

Comment: How is this better than other answer?